# Kafka Connect Transformation: What is the difference between `...$Key` and `...$Value`?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

## Question

[Kafka's Documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) on [Kafka Connect Transformation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_transforms) states the following:

> Use the concrete transformation type designed for the record key (`org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Key`) or value (`org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value`)

What is the difference between `...InsertField$Key` and `...InsertField$Value`, and when do we use either?

Furthermore, in general, what is the semantic purpose of having `...$Key` and `...$Value`? (I suppose for certain transformation, it may work on either the key or the value.)

## Details

The above section of document on Kafka Connect provided an example of how a `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField` transformation might be used. One part of the example requires setting the transformation type to `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value`.

There is no mention of `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Key` anywhere else besides the line quoted above. I can't think of a situation where `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Key` will be required, or how it will work differently.

## Places I've Looked

On the [Confluent docs on transformation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/index.html), it seems that certain transformation (e.g., `drop`) can either work on keys or values, and hence it makes sense to distinguish between `...$Key` and `...$Value`, and examples for both were given in the docs.

However, for transformation like `insert`, technically it doesn't make sense to talk about `...$Key` or `...$Value`, hence the docs only provided example of `...$Value`.

Answer (score 1):

Both keys and values of a Kafka record are capable of holding structured data. Insert transform therefore applies to both, for the same reason as drop

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. My original understanding was that both `InsertField$Key` and `InsertField$Value` inserts a new field (i.e., with both key and value). After reading the article at https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/, I understand that each Kafka record is a key-value pair, and the key and value themselves can consists of key-value pair(s). The `...$Key` and `...$Value` refers to the key-value at the record level, and not of the key-value of the key or value of the record.

Comment: Both will insert a key-value pairing into either the key or value struct of the record